# GCP permission issue when using default credentials in Go application

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

My application is fairly small:

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "google.golang.org/api/compute/v1"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    computeService, err := compute.NewService(ctx)
    urlMapCall := computeService.UrlMaps.List("my-prj")
    urlMaps, err := urlMapCall.Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    for _, mp := range urlMaps.Items {
        fmt.Println(mp.Name)
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.urlMaps.list' permission for 'projects/my-prj', forbidden
```

I have the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$HOME/.gcp/my-prj-aef233we.json` set. The service account this JSON represents has *Project Editor* and *Compute Admin* roles.

When I do `gcloud compute url-maps list`, it works without a flaw.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From GCP , it is also required to enable servceAccountUser role I guess

> roles/ compute.admin   Full control of all Compute Engine resources.
>
> If the user will be managing virtual machine instances that are
>   configured to run as a service account, you must also grant the
>   roles/iam.serviceAccountUser role.

Answer (score 1):

When you test with gcloud command, there is a lot of chance that you don't test with your service account but with your personal account. This means that you don't have the same level of permission, and thus the deference of observed behavior. Perform a `gcloud config list` to view the current configuration and user.

For the permission `compute.urlMaps.list`, 3 curated roles contain it

```
roles/compute.viewer
roles/compute.networkViewer
roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1
```

And don't forget to grant, in addition, the role `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`

Add one of them to your service account.

Answer (score 1):

My colleague identified the issue: I had given the *project-name* `my-prj` wrong. A `404` may have helped me identify the problem faster.

Thanks to the other answers, because adding the role *Service Account User* is needed.